# How to get character offset of a token when I parse it from a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, parsing

my code is like this:

```
int line_number = 0;
while (getline(infile, line)) {
        stringstream lineStream(line);
        line_number++;
        string token;
        while (lineStream >> token);
}
```

If some tokens are not what I expect, then I will output a syntax error with line number and character offset. But the question is how I'm able to get character offset, is there any simple way I can get tokens' first letter's position?

Comment: It might be possible to use `tellg()` to look at the updated position in the `stringstream()` after extracting a token, then subtracting the token's length. That feels iffy. In this kind of a situation, I would just parse each `line` manually, instead of using `stringstream`, and get down to the nitty-gritty details myself.

Comment: you mean, check character by character in each line?

Comment: Correct. A simple parsing loop.

Comment: That's going to give you the absolute stream position, you'd have to be careful to ensure you tracked the start-of-line tellg position: http://ideone.com/J1pjPL

Comment: `tellg()` is only useful for binary files... Also, your question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4821494/2706707).